# Successive Differentiation bSc

Tags: calculus

Question : If $x= a(\theta+ \sin \theta), y= a(1+\cos \theta)$, find $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ at $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

I got my answer matched in the textbook, fine.

Here is the problem:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -a\sin \theta$$ and then take the second derivative and we get the answer.

When I take $\dfrac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}$ and $\dfrac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}$ and divide them to get $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ I get the different answer ($\theta$ in this case)

Take $\dfrac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} \div \dfrac{d^2x}{d\theta^2} = \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Is this thing $\frac{ \dfrac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}}{ \dfrac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}}$ = $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} $ allowed in calculus?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Kindly use mathjax for math formatting. You can find help here:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think you have edited my question using mathjax

Comment: Yes, I did it for you this time! But you should keep this in mind that you need to do MathJax formatting before posting your question (or answer).

Comment: Please show me by applying the chain rule on it ...i didn't get any idea (even after applying chain rule) why that is the way to solve

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are currently in BSc I, your question is absolutely correct! At first, one might think

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} \div \dfrac{d^2x}{d\theta^2} = \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

should be allowed. Rather one might think that there is no reason for it to be not allowed. But, let us examine $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ carefully. Actually, it is the operator $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}$ being operated on $y$. Now, this operator $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}$ itself means that you have to operate $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ operator twice on $y$. Thus, we have

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)$$

Now, by chain rule, we can say that $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{d\theta} \dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$. This is allowed. Hence,

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dy}{d\theta} \dfrac{d\theta}{dx} \right)$$

You may now apply the product rule and see why the division (what you have specified) is not really the way to find $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.